# PyQt4 QSpinBox.selectAll() not working as expected

Tags: pyqt4, selectall

Python 2.5.4
PyQt4

I sub-classed a QDoubleSpinBox to emit a signal on a focusIn event:

```
#Custom widgets for DPL GUI
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 

class DPLDoubleSpinBox(QDoubleSpinBox):

    __pyqtSignals__ = ("valueChanged(double)", "focusIn()")

    def __init__(self, *args):
        QDoubleSpinBox.__init__(self, *args)

    def event(self, event):
        if(event.type()==QEvent.FocusIn):
            self.emit(SIGNAL("focusIn()"))
            #self.clear() Works as expected
            self.selectAll() #See below                  

        return QDoubleSpinBox.event(self, event)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = DPLDoubleSpinBox()
    widget2 = DPLDoubleSpinBox()
    widget.show()
    widget2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you click inside one box, then kill the other window, it works.  If you click inside one, then the other, then focus any other window on the desktop, it seems to work.

I think it's a focus problem, but can't track it down.  I just need it to select all when clicked on.  I tried doing it through its line edit pointer, but I get the same results.  Tried forcing focus to other widgets, but still same result.

You can connect a custom slot to fire when it emits "focusIn()".  You can then anyQSpinBox.selectAll(), and it works, just not on itself.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is more than two years old, but since it is one of the first results when googling "qspinbox select on focus", I would like to leave a solution for future generations.

The problem is the behavior of the QSpinBox.lineEdit(). With the focusInEvent, you can call selectAll(), but for some reason, the mousePressEvent of QLineEdit clears the selection right after the focus event. See [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8590) for an explanation.

The solution is to install an event filter for the QSpinBox.lineEdit() widget or subclass QLineEdit and call QSpinBox.setLineEdit(). Either way, the [link above](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8590) will show you how to achieve the desired behavior by keeping a boolean flag around and filtering both focusInEvent and mousePressEvent.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31705-selectAll-in-QLineEdit-does-not-work?p=277477#post277477), put a `QTimer.singleShot` call to `selectAll` inside the overriden `focusInEvent`, and then magic happens.

```py
class SpinBox(QSpinBox):
    def focusInEvent(self, event: QFocusEvent) -> None:
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.selectAll)
```

or like this (not recommended):

```py
b = QSpinBox()
b.focusInEvent = lambda _: QTimer.singleShot(0, b.selectAll)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the event to `QEvent.Enter`

Now it will `self.selectAll()`

I can get away with this because it's for a touch screen application, so it wouldn't be obvious to the user that something is amiss.  I'd still love to know what I'm missing, or if this is just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a follow up to @benjamin-kloster on this ancient thread as the forum link is dead but his answer was very helpful.

You can just subclass the QDoubleSpinBox and handle the FocusIn event. This was the most useful to me as I just wanted to select all on clicked so you can paste values into the spinbox easily.

I was using QtDesigner for the UI, so you need to promote your widget to the subclass below.

```
class Spinny(QDoubleSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QDoubleSpinBox.__init__(self, *args)

    def focusInEvent(self, event) -> None:
        if(event.type()==QEvent.FocusIn):
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self.selectAll)
```